# How to "un-subdivide" bones

Tags: armature, bones

Let's say I have a chain of bones and I want to reduce the number of bones in that chain by half. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **"Dissolve Bones"** in **Edit Mode**-Armature.

Select the bones to be removed and press "X" , a menu will popup with the Dissolve Bones option.